# Can I have async onChange handlers for react-final-form fields ? How to update the form state from an async function?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-final-form, form-fields

I'm thinking about adopting `react-final-form` to build some admin forms that I use on my web app.

I'll need to build an input component for image uploads that should be able to do the following.

- It's an `<input type="file"/>` element
- An image file should be selected
- That file should be uploaded to the bucket (ASYNC)
- And the returned URL (from the upload) should be added to the field value on the form
- Also the loading state should be triggered while the upload is being made

For example:

**1. Initial field state**

```
formState: 
  values: {
     thumbnail: {
        status: "IDLE"
        src: ""
     }
  }
  // OTHER FIELDS' VALUES
}
```

**2. During upload**

```
formState: 
  values: {
     thumbnail: {
        status: "UPLOADING"
        src: ""
     }
  }
  // OTHER FIELDS' VALUES
}
```

**3. After upload**

```
formState: 
  values: {
     thumbnail: {
        status: "IDLE"
        src: "THE_URL_RETURNED_FROM_THE_UPLOAD_API"
     }
  }
  // OTHER FIELDS' VALUES
}
```

Of course, I would also handle validation (image max size, etc) and possible errors from the API. But this simplified version illustrates well my requirements.

**PS:** I'm currently doing this with my own custom form solution (which uses Redux state, so I'm using `redux-thunks` to handle the async changes on the state).

The main reason I want to use `react-final-form` is to move the form state out of my Redux store.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to do with react final forms? How would I update the form state from that `async` `onChange` handler?

Comment: In my experience, file uploads are a bad match for form libraries that manage JSON data.

Comment: @ErikR. Thanks. It should still be regular JSON data. I'll only store the download `string` URL for the image. But in order to do that I need to handle the `async` upload separately will still being able to update the form once it completes.